# Compute the length of a line of latitude between two longitudes assuming a spherical Earth

Tags: coordinates, spherical-geometry

I am trying to compute the length between two longitude lines along a latitude line on a sphere.

I can find the great circle distance (haversine formula), and the straight line distance (cosine), but not the distance of the latitude line.

Comment: This was answered on the Math StackExchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233245/find-a-formula-for-the-great-circle-distance-between-two-points-on-the-same-lati/2247161#2247161